# Freeing Protobuf generated class causes a a segment fault

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers

Hi I am utilizing Protobuf for my personal project about neural networks.

Here is my Protobuf definitions:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package NGNET;

message InputLayer {
    string name = 1;
    uint32 size = 2;
}

message ComputeLayer {
    string name = 1;
    uint32 size = 2;
    repeated LayerLink inputs = 3;
}

message LayerLink {
    InputLayer il_input = 1;
    ComputeLayer cl_input = 2;
    uint32 output_size = 3;
    repeated float weights = 4;
}

message NNET {
    string name = 1;
    repeated ComputeLayer outputs = 3;
}
```

The network is created like this:

```
ComputeLayer output1 = ComputeLayer(10, "output1");
ComputeLayer output2 = ComputeLayer(10, "output2");
ComputeLayer hidden = ComputeLayer(100, "hidden");
InputLayer input1 = InputLayer(784, "input1");
InputLayer input2 = InputLayer(784, "input2");

output1.link(&hidden);
output2.link(&hidden);
hidden.link(&input1);
hidden.link(&input2);
hidden.link(&extra);
```

The link functions are defined as:

```
void ComputeLayer::link(ComputeLayer* to_link) {
  NGNET::LayerLink* link = new NGNET::LayerLink();
  link->set_output_size(internal->size());
  link->set_allocated_cl_input(to_link->getInternal());
  internal->mutable_inputs()->AddAllocated(link);
}

void ComputeLayer::link(InputLayer* to_link) {
  NGNET::LayerLink* link = new NGNET::LayerLink();
  link->set_output_size(internal->size());
  link->set_allocated_il_input(to_link->getInternal());
  internal->mutable_inputs()->AddAllocated(link);
}
```

Note: The `getInternal()` function returns a `NGNET::ComputeLayer` or `NGNET::InputLayer`

Then the outputs are liked to a NNET with:

```
nnet->mutable_outputs()->AddAllocated(output1->getInternal());
nnet->mutable_outputs()->AddAllocated(output2->getInternal());
```

When `nnet` is deleted the program crashes with a segment fault.

I believe this is due to the hidden layer gets deleted twice. Is there any way I can safely free the memory that was allocated ?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to figure out who owns what in your design. Currently, you tell multiple parties they all own the same message, so of course they all try to delete it, leading to double destruction. E.g. `set_allocated_Foo` is supposed to be called on a pointer wrestled from its prior owner via `release_Foo` - but you pass to it a pointer still owned by another proto.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When you say "You have to figure out who owns what in your design" do you mean that my design is not fit to be used in Protobuf or that I should be utilizing some other features of Protobuf that I don't know of ?

Comment: I don't really understand your design. On the surface, it seems like you are trying to model shared ownership. Protobufs are designed so that each message strictly owns values of its fields (which could in turn themselves be messages), and considers itself responsible for destroying them. You won't be able to get `LayerLink` proto merely point to a `ComputeLayer` proto, and not attempt to destroy the latter when the former itself is destroyed. Any shared ownership will have to be modeled by your own classes, outside the protobuf library.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah I see. I had a different understanding of Protobuf. I'm afraid it is not suitable for my project as the generated "tree" needs shared nodes. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_allocated_*()` and `set_allocated_*()` methods *take ownership* of the pointer they are given. This means that you have to make sure that no other code will delete those pointers later, because the Protobuf implementation will delete them when the message is destroyed.

If you don't want Protobuf to take ownership of these objects, you should make copies instead:

```
link->mutable_il_input()->CopyFrom(*to_link->getInternal());

nnet->mutable_outputs()->Add()->CopyFrom(*output2->getInternal());
```

Generally, unless you are doing intense memory allocation optimizations, you probably never want to call the "allocated" protobuf accessors.